# Как связать supervisor и скрипт python?

Tags: python-3.x, supervisord

Хочу запускать процессы супервизора в скрипте python, а не через консоль. Подскажите, как подружить команды консоли и python-скрипт, чтобы например в скрипте выполнялась команда
"cd /etc/supervisor/1.conf" и записывался файл процесса. То есть через скрипт питона в супервизор бы полностью добавлялся процесс.

Есть ли способы реализовать это?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался! Это можно делать с помощью os.popen